# Efficient Region Find Algorithm

Tags: graph-algorithm

Looking for a time efficient algorithm to decide the regions of a grid. Say you have a 16x16 grid, some tiles are white, some are black, and you are trying to find the disjoint regions of white tiles in that 16x16 grid. Seems like it might be some sort of union-find algorithm but I'm not sure - just wanted to figure out the most efficient way to do this.

Below is an example of a tile grid with 2 regions in it - the goal would be to assign a region ID to each white tile in that 2 dimensional array.

[image: Example of disjoint regions in a 16x16 tile grid]

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, basically a BFS, then scan for a tile that hasn't been assigned a region and isn't a black tile, then start BFS again, until you have scanned the whole 16x16 area

Comment: Looks like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill to me.